# Nextjs: update value with use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is my code:

```
export default function useUser(){
    var userToken = "one"

    function setToken(value: string) {
        userToken = value
    }

    return { userToken, setToken }
}
```

And this is my home:

```
export default function Home() {
    const { userToken, setToken } = useUser()

    console.log(userToken)
    setAccessToken("two");
    console.log(userToken)
}
```

I want to my result be: `one two`

But my code return: `one one`

Comment: I would recommend you to check out how [state works in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and what [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `userToken` is just a value output from the `useUser` call. As oppsed to that `setToken` is a function that has access to closure of `useUser`. To get it work as you expect add a getter method called `getToken` which will have access to the closure of `useUser` function.

```js
function useUser() {
  var userToken = "one";

  function setToken(value) {
    userToken = value;
  }

  function getToken() {
    return userToken;
  }

  return { getToken, setToken };
}

function Home() {
  const { getToken, setToken } = useUser();

  console.log(getToken());
  setToken("two");
  console.log(getToken());

  return (
    <div>
      {getToken()}{" "}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setToken("three");
          console.log(getToken());
        }}
      >
        click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

But still, it will not re-render anything for you after the button click. This is due to how React works it only renders when state changes. You should use `useState` hook for that.

Comment: It's wrong waye,